# Extract Part of File Name and Mutate into Column dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, xlsx, data-manipulation

I have an excel file called "data_12.18.2020.xlsx". I want to extract the date part of the file name and generate a date column as I read in the file. Is there a way to do this within a dplyr call?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the date from the filename using regular expression and add it as new column using `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)

file <- "data_12.18.2020.xlsx"
date <- sub('data_(\\d+\\.\\d+.\\d+)\\.xlsx', '\\1', file)
df <- read.xlsx(file) %>% mutate(date = date)
```